# Linking two event functions together synchronously

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of events that I listen to. A function in the second event `html.set` depends on the function in the first event `initialised` completing first. I've come up with a solution using promises, but it feels dirty. I'm wondering if this is the best way?

```
var applyGoogleFonts = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  editor.events.on('initialized', function() {
    _applyGoogleFonts().then(resolve);
  });
});

editor.events.on('html.set', function() {
  applyGoogleFonts.then(_setThemeFonts);
});
```

I should add that `_setThemeFonts` depends on the code before the trigger of `html.set` completing first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you'll find this cleaner, but just to suggest an alternative:

```
const waitForInit = new Promise(resolve => editor.events.on('initialized', resolve));
const waitForHtml = new Promise(resolve => editor.events.on('html.set', resolve));

waitForInit.then(_applyGoogleFonts).then(() => waitForHtml).then(_setThemeFonts);
```

It's important to subscribe to both events before waiting for the first one, because otherwise the second event could fire before the second subscription was added. Your code does this correctly as well.

Comment: Great answer :) It makes the logic much more explicit.

Comment: I found I had to do `waitForInitialized.then(_applyGoogleFonts).then(function() { return waitForHtmlSet }).then(_setThemeFonts);` in order for the theme fonts to be set after the `html.set`.

Comment: You're right, `.then()` doesn't accept promises as the argument. I've fixed the answer.